# Commandbar in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, commandbar

Ho to make Secondary Commands in C# in windows phone 8.1 (winprt) app?

```
//WINRT:
CommandBar CommandBarObject = new CommandBar();
AppBarButton FirstBtn = new AppBarButton() { Icon = new BitmapIcon() { UriSource = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/first.png") } };
FirstBtn.Label = "First";
FirstBtn.Click += FirstBtn_Click;
FirstBtn.IsEnabled = true;

CommandBarObject.PrimaryCommands.Add(FirstBtn);
CommandBarObject.SecondaryCommands.Add(secondaryCommand);
```

How to make this **secondaryCommand** now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put there *AppBarButton*:

```
 CommandBar CommandBarObject = new CommandBar();
 AppBarButton FirstBtn = new AppBarButton() { Icon = new BitmapIcon() { UriSource = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/first.png") } };
 FirstBtn.Label = "First";
 FirstBtn.Click += FirstBtn_Click;
 FirstBtn.IsEnabled = true;

 AppBarButton secondaryCommand = new AppBarButton() { Label = "Second", IsEnabled = true } };
 secondaryCommand.Click += FirstBtn_Click;

 CommandBarObject.PrimaryCommands.Add(FirstBtn);
 CommandBarObject.SecondaryCommands.Add(secondaryCommand);
```

Comment: Triied using the code, also added:             CommandBarObject = this.BottomAppBar as CommandBar;
 but the appbar is not displayed on page. what could be missing?

Comment: @AtifShabeer Have you set the BottomAppBar of your Page? `this.BottomAppBar = CommandBarObject;`

Comment: thanks a lot, it worked, and how to change the fontSize of texts of secondarycommand?

Comment: @AtifShabeer AFAIK you cannot change fontsize of secondary commands.